# Names for effects of sleep deprivation on the brain & body

Tags: sleep, neurology

When staying awake for a long period (3 or 4 days), some weird phenomena can occur. In my experience, it was always triggered by thinking too deeply and has in other occasions too.

Do these things have names at all?

Comment: The brain is a complex dynamic system; if you perturb it outside of its normal functioning parameters (for some examples: severe brain damage, psychadelic drugs, sleep deprivation), odd behavior can result. Note that sleep deprivation for ~2+ weeks kills rats. The rest of your question is too much based on personal health and experience to be on-topic here at Biology.SE.

Comment: “Deprivity”? Oh, I see, very clever pun on “depravity” and “deprivation”!

Comment: @BryanKrause, I completely disagree. The question of whether there are formal names for the mental changes the OP experienced during sleep deprivation seems to be fine.

Comment: @Michael_A Tried to make the question actually about that to keep it on topic, and retracted my close vote.

Comment: @BryanKrause, Nice. I thought the original description was a good attempt at describing the phenomena; it's a hard thing to describe. I agree that more words often make discerning the question harder.

Answer (score 3):

During extreme sleep deprivation you can briefly fall asleep, this is known as a [microsleep.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsleep) The disorientation that you experienced can be referred to as  [Hypogogia.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypnagogia)

Hypogogia covers a range of effects including visual and aural hallucinations as well as having thoughts that are experienced as [seeming logical during the microsleep but illogical once you're awake.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypnagogia#Cognitive_and_affective_phenomena)